# Child table is not mapping in OneToMany relationship in JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to establish **One to many** relationship between **User** and **Role**.

> One user can have many role.

Here is the code for User class

```
@Entity

public class User {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNo;

    @OneToMany(
                targetEntity = Role.class,
                mappedBy = "user", 
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY
              )
   
    private Set<Role> roles;        
     
    // Getters, setters and Constructor
```

Code for the Role class

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int roleId;
    private String role;  
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;       
    
    // Getters, setters and Constructor
        
  
   POST request on Postman is        

{
    "id":101,
    "name": "rahul",
    "password": "456",
    "email": "rahul@gmail.com",
    "phoneNo": "1234561234",
    "role": [{
        "role":"USER"
    }]
}
    
          
       

Code on Configuration part       
  
    @Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception
     {
        http.csrf().disable();
     }


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}         

     
Code On Controller part
   
@RestController
public class AdminController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encryptPassword;

    @PostMapping("/admin/add")
    public String addUserByAdmin(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        String pass = user.getPassword();
        String encrypt = encryptPassword.encode(pass);
        user.setPassword(encrypt);

        userRepo.save(user);
        return "User added Successfully";
    }
}
```

Role table connection to database through Jpa

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {
    
}
```

User table connection to database through Jpa

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer>{
    
}
```

Here problem is User table is mapped properly but Role table is not getting mapped.

```
roleId    role    user_id         
NULL      NULL    NULL
```

Where I am wrong ? Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you share the code (on a service) on how you are trying to save this?

Comment: @junbetterway  I have updated the code. Please look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your controller method below, have you tried debugging the incoming request **User** object?

Anyways, I have below points here:

First, looking into your request body, the field for your roles is named `role` while your User object has a field `roles` thus, I'm pretty sure it is `null` during your processing since it will not be deserialized there due to mismatch field names. Try changing your request body to something like this:

```
{
    "id":101,
    "name": "rahul",
    "password": "456",
    "email": "rahul@gmail.com",
    "phoneNo": "1234561234",
    "roles": [{
        "role":"USER"
    }]
}
```

Second, if you check your database, the roles will be persisted however your foreign key `user_id` is null. This is expected. The cascade you did on the **User** object will only means that (since you use **CascadeType.ALL**) once you save the **User** object the save operation will also be cascaded to the **Role** object however, JPA still needs to know the relationship thus you have to set the user for each role object. Hence, you can update your controller method to something below:

```
@PostMapping("/admin/add")
public String addUserByAdmin(@RequestBody User user)
{
  String pass = user.getPassword();
  String encrypt = encryptPassword.encode(pass);
  user.setPassword(encrypt);
  // JPA needs to know this relationship...
  user.getRoles().forEach(role -> role.setUser(user));
  userRepo.save(user);
  return "User added Successfully";
}
```

Now you can try and see that your expected behavior should now be happening.

**Additional recommendations:**

Why are we passing ID field on the user request? You can just remove that from your request body and use below to auto-generate your IDs to avoid Unique index or primary key violation exceptions on all of your entities:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

You can also remove the `targetEntity = Role.class` on the mapping as it is only used for generics and for your case clearly you are not using generics for Set. Update your **User** object for roles mapping:

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

Lastly, it is better if you can wrap your incoming payload to a DTO since you would not want to expose your entity/model to your API but I am thinking this is just for your test environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush the changes to the database when using `save()`, try this instead:

```
userRepo.saveAndFlush(user);
```